# Titles by Bertini and Weber alluded to in Gian-Carlo Rota’s foreword to Stanley’s Enumerative Combinatorics

Tags: reference-request

In the foreword to Stanley’s Enumerative Combinatorics is this paragraph:

> Every once in a long while, a textbook worthy of the name comes along; invariably, it is likely to prove aere perennius: Weber, Bertini, van der Warden, Feller, Dunford and Schwartz, Ahlfors, Stanley.

I know van Der Waerden’s "Modern Algebra", Feller’s "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Applications", Dunford and Schwartz’s "Linear Operators", Ahlfors’ "Complex Analysis" and/or "Riemann Surfaces".  But I’m unfamiliar with the particular textbooks that Weber or Bertini are known for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the **Ever-Green textbooks** written long ago , yet widely known & widely used , at certain earlier eras.

---

**Heinrich Weber** : Lehrbuch der Algebra [ "Textbook of algebra" ] :

https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Lehrbuch_der_Algebra.html?id=mJV3Z2hhwD0C

> Weber's three-volume set on algebra was for many years the standard text on algebra.
> Published at the end of the nineteenth century, it helped usher group theory to a central place in twentieth century mathematics.

---

**Eugenio Bertini** : Introduzione Alla Geometria Proiettiva Degli Iperspazi con Appendice Sulle Curve Algebriche e Loro Singolarità [ "Introduction to the Projective Geometry of Hyperspaces with Appendix on Algebraic Curves and Their Singularity" ] :

https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Introduzione_Alla_Geometria_Proiettiva_D.html?id=MSKGzwEACAAJ

> This work has been selected by scholars as being culturally important, and is part of the knowledge base of civilization as we know it.
> Scholars believe, and we concur, that this work is important enough to be preserved, reproduced, and made generally available to the public.

---

Gian-Carlo Rota , in the foreword , has given the list in a some-what Chronological Order , & these 2 are the "oldest" !
Hence , we might not know about it now & we might not even use the outdated & obsolete Content !

In a way , I think , Gian-Carlo Rota missed listing "The Elements" by Euclid.